# How to compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^\epsilon \ln x, \epsilon>0$?

Tags: limits

I need to compute $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^\epsilon \ln x, \epsilon>0$$

I tried to represent the limit as $$\dfrac{x^{\epsilon +1}\ln x}{x}$$

but it didn't work. Can you hint me?

Comment: What about $y = \frac1x$?

Comment: @Ilya I want to solve it using L'Hôpital's rule. Does your hint help to do it? Now I can see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using l'Hôpital rule:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x^{\epsilon}ln(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{ln(x)}{x^{-\epsilon}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\epsilon x^{-\epsilon-1} } = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{-x^{\epsilon}}{\epsilon} = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mention in the OP that you want to you L'Hopital, [what if I told you L'Hopital is not needed here?](http://hotmeme.net/media/mememaker/b/0/5153-what-if-morpheus-told-you.jpg) If you put $y = \frac1{x^\epsilon}$ you get a limit $-\frac1\epsilon\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{\log y}{y} =0.$

Comment: I understand you! But it's my exercise to solve it using L'Hôpital's rule. Anyway thanks for your help! :)