# Limit of $x\ln{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}x\ln{x}$$ which according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20x%20tends%20to%20o%20of%20xlnx) (and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)) equals $0$.

I managed to solve it by substituting such that $y = \dfrac{1}{x}$ and then using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\begin{align}
 \lim \limits_{x \to 0}x\ln{x} 
& = \lim \limits_{y \to \infty}\frac{\ln{\frac{1}{y}}}{y} \\
& = \lim \limits_{y \to \infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{y^2}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y}}}}{1} \\
& = \lim \limits_{y \to \infty}\frac{-1}{y} \\
& = 0
\end{align}$$

but my question is when I try to solve it using L'Hôpital's rule *without* making the substitution, I get:

$$\begin{align}
& \lim \limits_{x \to 0}x\ln{x} \\
& = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{x}+\ln{x} \\
& = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}1+\ln{x} \\
& = -\infty
\end{align}$$

So what went wrong here? Is it because I made $\frac{x}{x}=1$? If so how would I proceed from that point?

Or is this one of those cases where the caveat in L'Hôpital's rule that:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

has to exist is violated? Does equaling $-\infty$ count as not existing?

Comment: Remember what form you actually need for L'Hôpital's to apply. Differentiating $x\ln x$ isn't in that form.

Comment: You seem to have substituted $\frac{x}{x} + \ln x $ for $x \ln x$, which is incorrect at t the beginning.

Comment: @mardat oh because the denominator is $1$ and that doesn't tend to $0$? So in that case how should I solve this limit?

Comment: And doesn't have the same limit as the numerator.

To solve it, you could instead try, for example, $\frac{\ln x}{1\div x}$

Comment: @hardmath Not sure where you mean? I was differentiating but I realise that it's no good because it's not a fraction...

Comment: Indeed the problem is based on not knowing the limit of the "numerator", so we can't justify using L'Hopital's rule for that reason as well.

Comment: So is my first method with the substitution correct? Or just a lucky coincidence?

Comment: Try again but write $ x \ln x = \frac{\ln x}{1/x}$

Comment: @Dan your first method with the substitution is correct; the reason it worked where the second one didn't is essentially because it forced you to convert the equation into the form you needed.

Comment: Dan: You wrote $\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln x = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{x} + \ln x$, without justifying the step.  It appears then to be merely substituting $\frac{x}{x} + \ln x$ for $x \ln x$.  By the way, the limit should actually be taken from above (the right), by writing $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \ln x$.

Comment: @hardmath I see that now

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^\epsilon \ln x, \epsilon&gt;0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052822/how-to-compute-lim-x-to-0x-epsilon-ln-x-epsilon0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short if the limit of $f$ and $g$ are *both* zero or *both* $\pm\infty$, and the limit $f'/g'$ exists, then the limit $f/g$ equals it.

What's wrong is the expression $x\ln x$ as you are implicitly defining $f$ and $g$ doesn't meet the hypothesis. However if we write it as

$$\frac{\ln x}{1/x}$$

we can use l'Hopital with $f(x) = \ln x$, $g(x) = 1/x$ as

- The limits $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln x = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$; and
- The limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists as  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} -x = 0$

Hence $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x = 0$.

Comment: Right that's pretty simple. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan If this answered your question, you should consider setting it as [accepted](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: NB I removed an extra $=$ sign.

Comment: I have a small doubt. When x tends to 0 lnx will be a very small number say (-infinity) and x will tend to 0. So why does multiplying infinity to zero gives us 0 ? And LHL does not exist  so, will the limit exist ?

Comment: @user2414789 Yes, as the original question stands, $\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln x$ is potentially problematic as  it's not necessarily clear that negative $x$ are excluded. Everywhere the limits should be the right-hand limit, $x\to 0^+$. I've ended my answer to make that explicit. As to why in the product, $x$ and $\ln x$, $x \to 0$ "dominates" $\ln x \to -\infty$, that's what the mathematics shows. Of course there are other products where the limit could be other values. But in this case, $x\to 0$ "wins out".